# Does "now" in this BBC headline belong to the previous sentence or latter sentence? "Ukraine war: What is Putin's plan now Luhansk has fallen?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, conjunctions

This is a headline from the BBC at https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-62040787.

**"Ukraine war: What is Putin's plan now Luhansk has fallen?"**

The use of **"now"** here sounds different to me. Although it is a conjunction here, it seems to have two functions:

1-now (=now that)

2-now (=at present)(It can function as an adverb of "time" of the sentence before that: "What is his plan now?"

So I know that the **"now"** functions as a conjunction, but I also wonder if we want to invert the sentence, do we have to add another **"now"** to keep the meaning: **"Now Luhansk has fallen, what is Putin's plan now?**

Comment: see, for example, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/now#Conjunction

Comment: I would note that as an AME speaker I would normally expect "now that" rather than just the bare "now"

Comment: It's a headline so it uses an abbreviated style. Probably best not to learn grammar from headlines, even on the BBC.